# crawling an iframe with beautiful soup

Tags: javascript, python, iframe, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I´m trying to crawl specific information from a website but it somehow does not work for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357.124'}

output_file= open("Getyourguide.csv", "w", newline='') 
r = requests.get("http://www.getyourguide.de/s/?q=seoul")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("header", {"class": "activity-card-header"})
print(g_data)
```

print only this much:
    []

Hence, I had a deeper look into the html source and noticed it is that the information that I want to gather is from an Iframe most likely :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img alt="" height="1"    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/966398101/?label=ZXUsCLOE-gQQlaHozAM&amp;url=&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0&amp;data=" style="border-style:none;" width="1"/>
```

```
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-3XTJ" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

I have never crawled an Iframe. Therefore I´m not sure what my approach should look like in order to get certain information like the description, price and so on from the website. Could someone give me an hint. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you should find a 'div' with class "activity-card-header"? After a quick look at the source page I was able to find a 'header' element with this class but not a 'div' element.

Comment: My bad, you are right. It s a header element . But still I do not get any results back, just []  Is there any other solution?